# How do I make sure the EC2 instances behind loadbalancer are not directly accessible?

Tags: amazon-ec2, load-balancing

I have two EC2 instances behind a Amazon load balancer. The load balancer routes requests on port 80 to the instance port 80.

How do I make sure the instance services are accessible only through the loadbalancer DNS and not accessible directly through the instance public DNS ?

thanks 
Santhosh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be possible via appropriately setting the security groups for the EC2 instances, so that only connections from the Load Balancer are allowed.